# Residue class ring of Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Zariski and Samuel Commutative Algebra Ch V para 7 makes the following statement: If $R$  is a Dedekind domain with an ideal $\mathfrak{a}=\prod_i\mathfrak{p}_i^{n(i)}$ factored into prime ideals, then $R/\mathfrak{a}$ is the direct sum of rings isomorphic to the rings $R/\mathfrak{p}_i^{n(i)}$. Accepting the prime factorisation, can anyone point me at a proof of the direct sum decomposition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the Chinese remainder theorem, since the ideal factors are coprime, i.e., since we have $\mathfrak{p_i}^{n(i)}+\mathfrak{p_j}^{n(j)}=R$ for $i\neq j$. We have $\mathfrak{p}_i^{n(i)}\cap \mathfrak{p}_j^{n(j)}=\mathfrak{p}_i^{n(i)}\mathfrak{p}_j^{n(j)}$, so that
$$
R/\mathfrak{a}\cong \prod_{\mathfrak{p}}R/\mathfrak{p}^{\nu_p(\mathfrak{a})}.
$$